# Header only is displayed when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS snippet

```
<div class="glob-header">
    <p><?php echo $siteName; ?></p>
</div>
```

---

```
.glob-header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009AFF;
    height: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.glob-header p {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will display https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaa3q.jpg.
My problem is, when I zoom into the screen far enough, only the blue header is shown, even when I scroll down, I never get to the blank website body underneath the header. I've had this problem many times, can anyone offer a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: yes, thats coz its positioned absolute. it will always be stucked to top. Either zoom out or update your positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ajc said, *position:absolute* will give you problems.  You should also consider a more responsive design if you want it to work on different sized screens.  You might want to take a look at CSS media queries if you're going to be using work with drastically different sized screens (monitor vs phone).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp